# Структура базы данных для диалогов между пользователями

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, doctrine

Уже второй день не могу составить правильную структуру базы данных для сообщений между пользователями. Структура должна предполагать конференции.

Если кто-то сталкивался с данной задачей просьба поделится схемой базы.

Мой вариант:

Таблица для хранения общей информации по диалогу.

- id INT
- name VARCHAR(50)
- created TIMESTAMP

Таблица для хранения сообщений диалога - здесь будут храниться все сообщения привязанные к диалогу.

- id INT
- dialog_id INT
- sender_id INT
- text TEXT
- created TIMESTAMP

Таблица участников диалога

- dialog_id INT
- user_id INT
- joined TIMESTAMP (указывает, когда участник присоединился к диалогу,
  чтобы не показывать сообщения, которые были до того, как он
  присоединился)

Comment: Покажите свой вариант и мы вам поможем

Comment: @danilshik дополнил описание

Comment: @QuodNephilim чем не устраивает данная структура?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets по id пользователя невозможно получить диалог с ним

Comment: "Таблица участников диалога", выборка по user_id не отобразит список диалогов в которых участвует пользователь?